# Differentiability on boundaries

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

For example, consider the function $f: \  [0, 1] \mapsto \mathbb{R} $, $f(x)=x^2 $. Is it differentiable at $x=0$ and $x=1$? Intuitively I would guess no, because it doesn't make sense to talk about limits when the function is not defined on both sides of the considered point. If some more general definition was presented would it be possible?

This came to my mind when I was reading some basic calculus book. When trying to find the extrema of a function (for example $ \mathbb{R}^3 \mapsto \mathbb{R} $) it is said **separately** that one needs to check the points were the gradient is not defined but **also** the boundaries. I thought that talking about gradient on boundaries doesn't make any sense. But does a function have a gradient on a boundary point?

Comment: Please learn correct notation. You should write $f\colon [0,1]\to\Bbb R$, $f(x)=x^2$. Or $x\mapsto x^2$ with domain $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really a matter of convention, but I would say *yes*. For any function $f\colon A\to\Bbb R$, where $A\subseteq\Bbb R$, we say $f'(c)=d$ if
$$\lim\limits_{x\to c}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=d.$$
By definition, this means for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$0<|x-c|<\delta\qquad\text{implies}\qquad \left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-d\right|<\varepsilon.$$

Here's where you must decide exactly what the last phrase means. There are two options:

1. For all $x\in A$ such that $0<|x-c|<\delta$, we have $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-d\right|<\varepsilon$.
2. For all $x\in \Bbb R$ such that $0<|x-c|<\delta$, we have $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-d\right|<\varepsilon$.

Option $2$ doesn't really make sense because the expression $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-d\right|$ is not defined unless $f(x)$ is defined. On the other hand, option $1$ applies more generally, and one can indeed say "the function $f\colon[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ with $f(x)=x^2$ is differentiable at $0$." HOWEVER now you have some potentially unwanted results. For example, take $g\colon\{0\}\to\Bbb R$ with $g(0)=0$. According to the option $1$, $g$ is differentiable, but only because there are never any points $x\in A$ such that $0<|x-c|$. But then $f'(0)$ is not well-defined since it could be any value.

To deal with this, some authors simply define the derivative for interior points, and extend this to boundary points as we just did. This makes sense because the derivative, if it exists, is determined by looking at a one-sided limit on whichever side is actually in the domain.

Finally, I'll give another slight variation I like:

3. For all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $B(c,\delta)=A\cap ((c-\delta,c)\cup(c,c+\delta))$ is nonempty, and for any $x\in B(c,\delta)$, we have $\left|\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}-d\right|<\varepsilon$.

This agrees with the usual definition and also works on boundary points. It also works on any limit point of the domain. This ensures that, if $f$ is differentiable at $c$, then $f'(c)$ is well-defined. As an example, take $f\colon\{1/n:n\in\Bbb N\}\to\Bbb R$ where $f(x)=x^2$. The derivative is defined at only $x=0$, and we can say $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: Great! Is it possible to generalise the 3rd definition for a function of more than one variables?

Comment: @mathslover yes if you replace $B(c,\delta)$ with the punctured $\delta$-ball around $c$

Answer (score 1):

As you say, it does not make sense to talk about differentiability in a boundary point. In general, $x$ must be an interior point of the domain $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ of the function ($f:A\to\mathbb{R}^m$) in order to properly talk about what we mean by differentiability in $x$. The reason, as you also point out (but in this case, more generally) is that the *directional derivative* at $x$ must be defined for all directions, and this doesn’t happen if $x$ is not an interior point of $A$ (i.e., if there doesn’t exist a ball centered at $x$ which is completely contained in $A$).